# jQuery: Check / uncheck all siblings with certain class

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors, checked, siblings

I am new to jQuery and hope someone here can help me with this question.

I am trying to **set up an "All" checkbox** to check / uncheck all its sibling checkboxes (i.e. those under the same div / parent) - but only if they DO NOT have a certain class (`"other"`).

My approach was to cause the least run time and to write this in a way that it can also be applied to similar structures in other divs.

The code I have works without the `:not()` selector but I can't get it to work when I include this. 
Also, I am not sure if my approach is the best / fastest way here.

**My jQuery:**

```
$('.checkAll').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).siblings(":not($('.other'))").prop('checked', true);
    }else{
        $(this).siblings(":not($('.other'))").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help, 
Mike

Comment: From w3.org: `Note: During the handling of a click event on an input element with a type attribute that has the value "radio" or "checkbox", some implementations may change the value of this property before the event is being dispatched in the document.` So you should use `change` event instead even all modern browsers support `click` event nicely AFAIK. EDIT: just checked jQuery source and as usual, this is taking into account (normalized), see code below:

Comment: `/* For checkbox, fire native event so checked state will be right */
   trigger: function() {
    if ( jQuery.nodeName( this, "input" ) && this.type === "checkbox" && this.click ) {
     this.click();
     return false;
    }
   },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `jQuery Selector` inside `:not`.

```
$('.checkAll').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings(":not('.other')").prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

`$(this).is(':checked')` returns `true/false` which you have checked using `if` and assigned the same to the `checked`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - this helped a lot ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: Just to do this right in the future, can you explain the last part in your code ? Is this just a short way of writing the if statement ?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `$` within `:not`. You can optimize the code you using this.checked and avoid the if statement.

```
$('.checkAll').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings(":not('.other')").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove jquery object in not selector ,you can use string

```
 $(this).siblings(":not('.other')").prop('checked', true);
```